# How to Execute Service inside Docker Container On Startup without CMD?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have multiple services of Burp Suite Enterprise bundled in a .sh script.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "========= Starting Burp Enterprise Edition Agent..."
systemctl start burpsuiteenterpriseedition_agent

echo "========= Starting Burp Enterprise Edition Database..."
systemctl start burpsuiteenterpriseedition_db

echo "========= Starting Burp Enterprise Edition Server..."
systemctl start burpsuiteenterpriseedition_enterpriseserver

echo "========= Starting Burp Enterprise Edition WebServer..."
systemctl start burpsuiteenterpriseedition_webserver

echo "========= ALL BURP SERVICES STARTED SUCCESFULLY!"
```

This script should be launched when docker run or docker exec is done.

This does work with a CMD line but since the ENTRYPOINT will be put on a dotnet app later I want to make sure when the docker run is initiated the services will be started.

The service is called: **burp-starter.service** which should activate the .sh script.

This are the lines that are currently inside the dockerfile:

```
COPY ./Scripts/. /root
RUN chmod u+x burp-services.sh
RUN mv /root/burp-starter.service /etc/systemd/system/burp-starter.service && chmod 644 /etc/systemd/system/burp-starter.service
RUN systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl enable burp-starter
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/root/burp-services.sh"]
```

But now I want to use something different instead of CMD, because the ENTRYPOINT will be changed to the dotnet application later.

Is this possible?

Comment: A Docker container usually only runs one process.  Systemd wants to manage a broad swath of hardware and system daemons and those just aren't present in a container.  I'd either suggest breaking this setup into multiple containers, maybe using Docker Compose, or setting this up as a proper virtual machine instead.

Comment: I agree with David's point about using multiple containers, but just as another idea, could you have the shell script execute the dot application also?

Comment: What I do now is I run the docker container, use the command to enable Burp and then change the ENTRYPOINT to a shell script.